# XHR error loading traceur.js while using react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

When I'm trying to start project with react-select I have XHR error loading traceur.js. I import library how it's written in official guide. When I'm trying use react-select in codesandbox it works correct. In my project even when I import `import Select from 'react-...'` IDEA's autocomplete doesn't see 'react-select'

I don't understand why this error appears and why

Did anyone have issue like this?

Comment: Search for 'react-select' in package.json. Do you see it, and its version?

Comment: Yes, I have last version "react-select": "3.1.0"

Comment: Post the link to your codesandbox

Comment: Codesandbox works correctly. I don't have problems with it, I tried react-select there to understand what is wrong. I have an issue in my project, I can't send link to it.